# Htaccess Maintenance Mode Exlude 1 Domain

Tags: .htaccess, multiple-domains, maintenance-mode

We have add-on domains to the same directory of our website, 1 of the domain is for us to access and test the website. I want to activate Maintenance mode excluding our test domain so we can access the site and do our tests.

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` is to test the domain name. If the `HTTP_HOST` is not the test.com domain, and the `REQUEST_URI` is not the maintenance.php (to prevent a redirect loop) redirect the traffic to the maintenance page.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance.php$

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /maintenance.php?$1 [R=301]
```